# How to localize HeaderText in GridView or validation controls?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, localization

I cannot figure out why HeaderText or validation controls always fallback to default culture - even though rest of the controls are in correct culture.

I have a GridView with HeaderText specified in this way>

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="totalSales" HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Strings,TotalSales %>" />
```

In the same way I have validation controls and they can't be localized.

Only this syntax does work: `<%= Resources.Strings.Payments %>`

I set different culture in Master page using this statement in Page_Init

```
Me.Page.Culture = "pl-PL"
Me.Page.UICulture = "pl-PL"
```

Can anyone spot what's wrong? I have been Googling it for last few days without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use ExpressionBuilder? That works very well and allows you to localize everything using the same approach.